# how can i bring html file in my nodejs file using express static at ubuntu?

Tags: node.js

```
const express =require('express');
const app= express();
const morgan= require('morgan');
const mysql= require('mysql');
//const path= require('path')

app.use(express.static('pub'));
```

At ubuntu my app.js file is in /home/ubuntu/u and form.html file is in /home/ubuntu/u/pub

So I want to use form.html file in app.js but I can only get:

```
::ffff:175.194.23.67 - - [23/Jan/2020:16:23:07 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36"
```

(this message by terminal).

I tried to use `__dirname` or `static` but they were not useful. What is the problem in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Pls try with this

```
app.use(express.static(`${__dirname}/pub`));
```